# Can I generate my Public Key and Private Key pair where my Public Key is publicly trusted (CA Certification)

Tags: ssl, openssl

One of my client is asking CA Certified Public Key for Encryption/Decryption purpose. And I am not sure how to provide it to them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can reach the Public/Private Key providers to get the key pair (for eg: SSL.com but i am not sure which one is good.)Public key - can be shared with every one but keep the private key as a secret. The information encrypted by your public key can be decrypted only with your private key.

Comment: That's fine, but can I export both public and private key?

Comment: I couldn't understand your qn. Export to where?